# Cannot delete file created using bash script

Tags: raspbian, python, script, permissions

I'm having a problem with file permissions...
Iv'e got a python program to automatically take pictures using fswebcam (by running a bash script using subprocess.call). however when i try to delete these files from my mac (SSH) (or even from the pi command line `rm -r` without sudo) i dont have permission.

if i run the fswebcam command myself i can delete it.

when created with the script it is owned by root (in group pi) and owned by pi if i run it (and in group pi). Even when i chmod the file to 777 i cannot delete it.

Any solutions?

EDIT: The permissions for the containing folder is `drwxr-sr-x`. This folder is created using `os.mkdir("folder_name")`, how do i stop this from creating the folder as both setuid bit and execute bit?

Comment: Check the ownership and permissions of the directory. Deleting a file requires permission to modify the directory.

Comment: The directories permissions are: drwxr-sr-x. I dont know what the 's' is :/ These created using os.mkdir("folder_name").

Comment: Do you have any dmask bits or umask bits set in your fstab file? How is your drive(s) mounted?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the files are owned by the user running the python script.
My guess is that you are probably running that as root?

when doing an ls -l you will see the permission bits, owner and group.

ie:

```
ls -l
```

returns:

```
-rwxr--r--   1 root wheel  278 Nov 20 13:22 derp.sh
```

this means that the file 'derp.sh' is owned by the user "root". "wheel" is the group in this case.

-rwxr--r-- can be split up in 3 parts: owner - group - other like so:

- | rwx | r-- | r--   We can ignore the first "-" here.

(Other means anyone that doesn't match the owner or isnt in the group)

**R** means **READ**

**W** means **WRITE**

**X** means **EXECUTE**

so in this example:

Root is the owner of the file and can read write and execute this file.

Anyone in the wheel group can read this file.

All other users can also read this file.